# Customer transactions over time modeling with Poisson Law

Tags: probability

In an article of Bruce Hardie, it is written:

> While alive, the number of transactions made by a customer follows a Poisson process with
>   transaction rate $λ$ ; therefore the probability of observing $x$ transactions in the time interval $(0 ,t]$ is given by:
>   $P(X(t)=x\mid λ)=(λt)^x \frac {e^{−λt}}{x!}$, for $x=0,1,2,\dots$
>
> This is equivalent to assuming that the time between transactions is distributed exponential with transaction rate $λ$, as follows: $f(t_j−t_{j−1}|λ)=λe^{−λ(t_j−t_{j−1})}$, with $t_j>t_{j−1}>0$

I want to prove this equivalence, but I really have no clue. Can someone help me to understand this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With transaction times $T_1,T_2,\dots$, consider, for $t>0$:
\begin{align*}
\mathbf{P}(T_{j+1}-T_j>t)&=\mathbf{P}(X(T_j)=X(T_j+t))\quad\text{since no transactions between }T_j\text{ & } T_j+t \\
&=\mathbf{P}(X(T_j+t)-X(T_j)=0)\\
&=\mathbf{P}(X(t)=0)\\
&=(\lambda t)^0\frac{e^{-\lambda t}}{0!}=e^{-\lambda t}.
\end{align*}
The equality between the second and third lines--independence of increments--follows from the definition of a Poisson process. So,
\begin{align*}
\mathbf{P}(T_{j+1}-T_j\leq t)&=1-e^{-\lambda t},
\end{align*}
which means $T_{j+1}-T_{j}$ is exponential with parameter $\lambda$. In other words, the density of the time between transactions is:
\begin{align*}
f(t)&=\lambda e^{-\lambda t},\quad t>0\\
f(t_{j+1}-t_j)&=\lambda e^{-\lambda (t_{j+1}-t_j)},\quad t_{j+1}>t_j\quad(\text{by letting }t=t_{j+1}-t_j)
\end{align*}